# Unable to set the package name for classpath in randoop

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, randoop

Here the project structure cloned from github after  compiling on Ubuntu successfully,

```
javaml 
     bin
       net/sf/javaml/core/Dataset.class
javaml
     src
      net/sf/javaml/core/Dataset.java
```

When the following command wa given:

```
java -ea -classpath /home/shahid/git/javaml/bin:/home/shahid/a_f_w/randoop-3.1.5/randoop-all-3.1.5.jar  randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=net.sf.javaml.core.Dataset --literals-file=CLASSES
```

It generated the error: "Ignoring interface net.sf.javaml.core.Dataset specified via --classlist or --testclass.
No classes to test
".

while the other command

```
java -ea -classpath /home/shahid/git/java-ml/bin:/home/shahid/a_f_w/randoop-3.1.5/randoop-all-3.1.5.jar  randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=DataSet --literals-file=CLASSES
```

without package for other project working perfectly. 
Any help will be appretiated.

Comment: The other project is also downloaded from github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message gives you the answer:

> Ignoring interface net.sf.javaml.core.Dataset specified via --classlist or --testclass. No classes to test

You are supposed to provide a class, not an interface, to the `--testclass` command-line argument.

By passing `--testclass=net.sf.javaml.core.Dataset` to Randoop, you indicated that you only want Randoop to create objects of type `net.sf.javaml.core.Dataset`.  However, since that is an interface, it cannot be instantiated, and Randoop cannot create any objects, nor any tests.

Comment: When the command:                                                                                               "java -ea -classpath ~/randoop.jar:~/lib/javaml-0.1.7.jar randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=Dataset --literals-file=CLASSES --ignore-flaky-tests=true  --only-test-public-members=true" was given,      the error generated was "policy = sun.security.provider.PolicyFile@4dd8dc3"
Throwable thrown while handling command: java.lang.Error: No class found for type name "Dataset"java.lang.Error: No class found for type name "Dataset" at randoop.main."

Comment: This error message says the same thing:  `Dataset` is not a fully-qualified path on your classpath.  (The "policy = ..." output is not part of the error message.)

Comment: a similar issue was raised to randoop v 2.1.0 as given in the link "https://github.com/rjust/defects4j/issues/25" and solved by using the randoop v 2.1.2. I have tried all the versions but it is not resolving. Even giving the class path in double quotes.

Comment: You still haven't produced a reproducible test case, as requested in the [Randoop manual](https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/#getting_help).  You have just provided random command lines and complained that it doesn't work.  Reading the messages has revealed a number of problems, so that is a good thing for you to do.  More importantly, if you aren't willing to provide a reproducable test case, then others can't help you.

Comment: There is no test case generated, randoop terminates as the error appear, here is the link to the screenshot taken of the terminal Stack [pt.so]https://www.dropbox.com/s/zgxk6b1tddzuq9k/Screenshot%20from%202017-07-31%2005-29-00.png?dl=0[pt.so] <br> and here is the link to randoop version used  [pt.so] https://www.dropbox.com/sh/p90gxo23phcxpdk/AAAAV1tmbliFLmfy30J_-W7Ka?dl=0 [pt.so] </br>

Comment: I have multiple times given you the URL to the [Randoop manual](https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/index.html#getting_help) where it tells you how to report a test case, and what information is needed.  Just a screenshot is not enough!

Comment: I was unable to generate the test cases by using prior versions but the 3.1.4 worked for me correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked for me:

```
java -ea -classpath ~/javaml/bin/:~/Randoop/randoop-all-3.1.4.jar  randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=net.sf.javaml.core.Complex --literals-file=CLASSES
```

@mernst thanks for your kind response.